# Join query with two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL query that didn't return any rows. I checked those tables which contain data so I think my query is incorrect.

[image: this is first table(sales_items[![this is second table(sales_payment)])][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nl9KH.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VK6y.jpg)

my query is:

```
SELECT payment_type,with_service_total,sale_nm 
FROM `ospos_sales_payments` 
INNER JOIN ospos_sales_items ON ospos_sales_payments.sale_id = ospos_sales_items.sale_id 
WHERE 'sale_id' = '236'
```

Comment: there's also no php here.

Comment: [way ahead of you...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42144124/join-query-with-two-tables#comment71454744_42144124) @JonathanKuhn ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- yea, but yours wasn't a close vote.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn True; I voted too soon earlier, darn it *lol* I only typed it all out.

Comment: @Fred-ii- mine was the auto comment from just copying your link.

Answer (score 4):

The error is in your syntax. You are doing `WHERE 'sale_id' = '236'`, so you are comparing two different strings, and this condition will always evaluate to `FALSE`.

Your query should be written like this:

```
SELECT 
  payment_type,
  with_service_total,
  sale_nm 
FROM `ospos_sales_payments` 
INNER JOIN ospos_sales_items 
  ON ospos_sales_payments.sale_id = ospos_sales_items.sale_id 
WHERE sale_id = '236'
```

Also, if the `sale_id` field is numeric, you can compare to `236` also without using quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Remove quote and add table name:

```
WHERE ospos_sales_payments.sale_id = '236'
```

or

```
WHERE `ospos_sales_payments`.`sale_id` = '236'
```